# What is the difference between active and passive fingerprinting?

Tags: authentication, network-programming

Currently I am studying about how exactly the bluetooth works and I came across the terms *active* and *passive* fingerprinting techniques. Could anybody explain these terms to me or give me some pointers to literature?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know enough about Bluetooth to give a specific answer about fingerprinting it, however, your question seems general, so I'll try giving a general answer.

In general, passive techniques are techniques that don't require active participation in the network. So they can be done without sending packets or frames, just by listening. This means that passive techniques are very hard to detect, but are more limited.

In the case of Bluetooth, **passive fingerprinting** can probably be done by listening to beacon frames, or perhaps a conversation between two of more devices.

**Active fingerprinting**, on the other hand, requires you to send frames into the network, to device(s) being fingerprinted, and listening to the response(s).